# Різниця між словами "наречений" і "жених"

Tags: синоніми, стилістика

Чи є яка-небудь стилістична диференціація синонімів **[наречений](http://sum.in.ua/s/narechenyj)** і **[жених](http://sum.in.ua/s/zhenykh)**? Я вважала, що **[жених](http://sum.in.ua/s/zhenykh)** є розмовним, а виявилося - лише в одному значенні (за Академічним тлумачним словником):

> розм. Про молодого чоловіка, що може вже одружуватися.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Академічний тлумачний словник - це витвір сталінської школи української мови від Бєлодєда. Як на мене, він добрий для швидкої довідки, але не може бути авторитетним, щоб визначати реальний вжиток.

Словник Єфремова-Кримського не дає "жених" ні як розмовне, ні як рідковживане.

> *Жени́х* –
>
> 1. жени́х, нарече́ний, молоди́й.
>    • -ни́х и невеста – молоди́й і молода́, молоді́, ум. молодя́та, (в свад. песнях) князь і княги́ня;
> 2. (молодой человек) молоди́к, (шутл.) жени́ло.

Джерело: [Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

Як бачите, наше *"жених"* дане як перший відповідник російського слова *"жених"*. Вжиток підтверджується численними прикладами з класики, які можна побачити також за посиланням.